# Jenkins - Selenium : Trying to get access to testng failed.xml.? Where will this file be located when scripts are ran through jenkins

Tags: jenkins, testng

Currently it consumes so much time to rerun the filed test cases from Jenkins in My LOCAL MACHINE.And most of the test would pass locally .

Is there anything I can do to cut short the time ?

Answer (score 0):

TestNG generates all of the artifacts viz.,

1. Html reports
2. Emailable report
3. JUnit styled xml reports
4. TestNG XML reports
5. testng-failed.xml

by default in the output directory of your project. If its not defined, TestNG defaults to `test-output` folder.

When tests are run via build tools such as maven wherein you leverage the surefire plugin, then this output directory gets configured to point to `target/surefire-reports` directory.

So your `testng-failed.xml` if it gets generated, will be available in your `$WORKSPACE\target\surefire-reports` directory (Here `$WORKSPACE` represents your Jenkins job's workspace)